# Enlazar varios archivos C++ en Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, vscode

¡Hola Stackoverflow! ¿Cómo vinculo(enlazar) varios archivos C ++ (.cpp, .h)? En la programación orientada a objetos con C ++,en una clase se separa la interfaz de la implementación (archivo de encabezado .h es la interfaz, archivo .cpp de implementacion de la clase). Y hay un tercer archivo .cpp que contiene la función main. ¿Cómo se compilan y vinculan(enlanzan esos tres archivos en Visual Studio Code? Utilizo compilador MinGW. Cómo crear un proyecto C++ con cmake en Visual Studio Code ?

Comment: Pues si usas MinGW solo tendrias que añadir el archivo `.cpp` donde implementas la clase junto al del main. `g++ main.cpp clase.cpp [otros flags]`. Con respecto a "*Cómo crear un proyecto C++ con cmake en Visual Studio Code?*", para esto te conviene mas seguir el tutorial que [encuentras en la documentacion de cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/guide/tutorial/index.html).